# Call a function like : <function> <statement>

Tags: javascript, syntax

I know that `break`, `continue`, and `return` functions are built-in.

But I saw http://summerofgoto.com/ which allow to write `goto <label>`.

What should we write so that we can call funcitons like this?

N.B: I get the error : `Missing ; before statement` if I write `foo bar;`

Comment: If your point is that you want to call functions without parentheses, then you may want to check out http://coffeescript.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not. ["Summerofgoto" / "goto.js"](http://summerofgoto.com/js/goto.js) is using an awkward hack to enable this statement: it parses the JS source code line by line and uses Regular Expressions to find patterns like "goto xy;".

Basically, ["goto.js"](http://summerofgoto.com/js/goto.js) it is a preprocessor for JavaScript which rewrites your actual code (containing labels and goto) into regular JS - it replaces your labels and goto statements to functions and function calls.

You could do the same thing, though. However, for performance reasons i strongly suggest you don't.

"break" and the like are not functions, they are statements which are part of the core language. thats a whole different thing.

Comment: Same for `[lbl] <label_name>` ?

Comment: I don't think there's anything weird about preprocessing the code. Many DSLs are designed that way and, besides, remember C preprocessor?..

Comment: @MikhailKozhevnikov I didn't want to say you should never do any pre-processing. But in this case - only for the sake of omitting the parenthesis - i find that is a stupid idea and simply overhead.

Comment: @Kaii that's for sure. Besides, in a language as flexible as javascript I really see no need for goto.

Answer (score 1):

`goto.js` is stealthy. Instead of actually running your scripts as Javascript, it reads the document's `<script type="text/jsplusgoto">` (*not* `text/javascript`!), then rewrites the labels and gotos into actual Javascript.

Whatever you're looking to do, that technique is almost certainly overkill.

Answer (score 1):

These are keywords of the language, not functions. When one wants to extend a language with new keywords, the code containing such keywords generally has to be parsed and every occurrence of every new keyword replaced with a function call or other suitable construction available in the original language.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that `break`, `continue`, and `return` functions are built-in.

`break`, `continue`, and `return` are not functions at all.  Generally `goto` is considered harmful and `break`, `continue`, and any `return` in the middle of a function are goto.